# Which generic data structure in C# is capable of substituting a 2d array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I know that `List<T>` is widely used as a substitute for 1d naked arrays (e.g. `int [] arr`) in C#.

Which standard .NET framework data structure is capable of substituting a 2d array (e.g. either `int [,] arr` or `int [][] arr`)?

Comment: `List<List<int>>`?

Comment: Since `int[][]` is an array of `int[]` arrays, so its substitute would be `List<int>[]`. Since that is also an array, it could again be substituted by `List<List<int>>` (what juharr already mentioned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement a generic-ish version of `int[,]`, You can use a `Dictionary` with a multidimensional key such as

```cs
    public struct TwoDims : IEquatable<TwoDims>
    {
        int X;
        int Y;

        public bool Equals(TwoDims other) 
        { 
            return (this.X == other.X) && (this.Y == other.Y); 
        }
    }
```

with an implementation like:

```cs
    public class Matrix
    {
        public Dictionary<TwoDims, double> Values 
                = new Dictionary<TwoDims, double>();
    }
```

Comment: Is this something you have made up for this answer, or you used it in your projects?

Comment: yes and no.  I have used a similar struct 'NDims' as a key for n-dimensional dictionary, mostly because n was dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Nested Lists:

```
List<List<T>> myList = new List<List<T>>();
```